# What is the best data type to represent the time duration of something on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to know if there is a correct data type to represent the time duration of something. For example, in my case I need to store the reading time of a book or how long did a person spent in a page.

I'm in doubt between `int`, `timestamp` and `datetime`.

Thank you.

Comment: The best data type would be `DATETIME`

Comment: DATETIME obviously makes no sense in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `int`, why?

`timestamp` and `datetime` are used to set a specific date/time moment, so these data types are useful if you want to know when someone started/finished to read the book, in the other hand, `int` will allow you to save a duration in seconds or something like that and then in your program you can convert it to years, months, days, hours, etc

Comment: That's what I thought, but then I researched and there are people using `DATETIME`.